# MySql: Evenly distributed sample size on unevenly distributed data

Tags: mysql, select, distribution, sample

Let's say I have 10.000 booking customer profiles.
These profiles have the following variables:

- Duration (days to go on holiday)
- Destination (maybe Brazil)
- People_amount (how many go with)
- Takeoff (date when they want to leave)

I want to pass 1.000 (10%) of them through a booking engine for pricing, but to develop an independent insights analysis I have to (as much as I can) evenly distribute the characteristics of the profiles. E.g. if all the the profiles have 3 varieties of People_amount (1, 2 and 3), ultimately I would like to have a selection within the 10% of 33,33% with People_amount = 1, 33,33% with People_amount = 2 and 33,33% with People_amount = 3.

But...

Because the profile set isn't evenly distributed (for example 70% of all profiles consist of People_amount = 1) I can't figure out how to maybe find/create a sort of loop (or something else) that fills up the SELECT by all varieties within that characteristic untill 1 is exhausted and goes further with the rest.

Maybe an example on how I would like to fill up the 10% sample of my 10k profiles:

> ```
> Profile_id  People_amount                                     Profile_id  People_amount
> 1           1                                                           1           1
> 2           1                                                           5           2
> 3           1                                                           8           3
> 4           1       --> Filling the sample by even distribution         2           1
> 5           2       of available profile characteristics                6           2
> 6           2                                                           9           3   
> 7           2                                                           3           1
> 8           3                                                           7           2
> 9           3                                                           4           1
> ```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) for that with a limit on each sub select:

```
(SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE People_amount=1 LIMIT 333)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE People_amount=2 LIMIT 333)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE People_amount=3 LIMIT 333)
```

The brackets are needed to apply the `LIMIT` to each sub select.

#### A more dynamic approach

In case the number of possible values of `people_amount` is not known, the above method is not workable. Then I would propose a query where the `ORDER BY` clause distributes `people_amount` values based on number of occurrences. It will not give an exact equal distribution, but the distinct values will have a comparable presence in the result set:

```
select     p.*
from       (
            select   people_amount,  
                     count(*) as occurrences
            from     profiles
            group by people_amount) as stats
inner join profiles p
        on p.people_amount = stats.people_amount         
order by   rand() * stats.occurrences
limit      1000
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e5e4/2) (if not overloaded).

If you want to extend this to other columns, like `Destination`, you could do that as follows:

```
select     p.*
from       (
            select   people_amount,  
                     destination,
                     count(*) as occurrences
            from     profiles
            group by people_amount,
                     destination) as stats
inner join profiles p
        on p.people_amount = stats.people_amount         
       and p.destination = stats.destination
order by   rand() * stats.occurrences
limit      1000
```

The idea is that values that have low occurrences will get lower order-by values, and so will pop up more often in the beginning of the result set, compensating for their low frequency.

Comment: Thanks @trincot.

What you provided comes al long way, but it indeed LIMITs the result for that value. What I need is something that exhausts every existing value per column until it hits (according to my example) a 1.000 rows in total.
On top of that (because Destination can consist of 20 different values and Takeoff maybe 50) I would like to no hard code the "People_mount = 1". If this could be dynamic, dependent on all the values available, this would make it more scalable.

Comment: *exhausts very existing value per column*: Some combinations of destination, people_amount and take off date will not be in the sample, just because there are two many combinations possible (more than 1000). Maybe you should rephrase your question to shed light on this. Also I assume this requirement does not apply to profile_id.

Comment: Spell correction: I meant 'every' in stead of 'very existing value per column'.
Maybe it is better to indeed make it smaller/chop it into pieces to better understand. By keeping it to my example of People_amount there are 3 value (1,2 and 3). Let's say I don't want to figure out by myself how many different values there are (because there are too many), how can we make the value of '1' in People_amount=1 dynamically based in the different values in the column?

Comment: Superb!!!! True that the spread won't be exactly, but with a sample of more than 1k it wil be more precise than with 10 when using more columns. TIP: I found a missing ',' after the first 'destination' in the second script. Could you ament that for future users?

Comment: Corrected! Thanks.